How to bind generic generated checkboxes with enum flags in WPF?
We have a Person who can have several Skills (Strength, Intelligence and Luck). In our WPF-Application, we want to bind these Skills to Checkboxes. When a Person has these Skills in his list, then the Checkboxes should be checked:

The Person Class and Enum:
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }    

    public List<SkillsEnum> Skills { get; set; } // <-- The skills of the user
}

public enum SkillsEnum // <-- All available skills
{ 
    Strength,
    Intelligence,
    Luck
}

Our View Model:
public class InitAppViewModel : ViewModelBase
{    
    public Person CurrentPerson { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> AvailableSkills
    {
        get { return Enum.GetNames(typeof(SkillsEnum)).ToList(); }
    }

    public InitAppViewModel()
    {
        CurrentPerson = new Person() { Name = "Foo", Skills = new List<SkillsEnum> { SkillsEnum.Luck, SkillsEnum.Intelligence } };
    }
}

The respective XAML-Markup:
<ItemsControl x:Name="CurrentPerson_Skills" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableSkills}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}, Path=DataContext.CurrentPerson.Skills, Converter={StaticResource SkillToBoolConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

The Converter:
public class SkillToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // conversion code here which returns a boolean
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}

How can we bind (two-way binding) the checkboxes with the Skill-List?

As a note, List<SkillsEnum> seems to be redundant here. You could make SkillsEnum a flag enum. Then you could do something like shown here.

You can use  IMultiValueConverter:
public class SkillToBoolConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var currenSkill = (string)values[0];
        var personSkills = (List<SkillsEnum>)values[1];
        return personSkills.Any(s => Enum.GetName(s) == currenSkill);

    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

In Xaml:
 <ItemsControl x:Name="CurrentPerson_Skills" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableSkills}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" >
                 <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                     <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SkillToBoolConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
                         <Binding/>
                         <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}" Path="DataContext.CurrentPerson.Skills"/>
                     </MultiBinding>
                 </CheckBox.IsChecked>
             </CheckBox>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>

and set "command" attribute of CheckBox for add/remove skill person

Although not explicitly asked for in the question, it seems obvious that the Binding should work TwoWay.

That's why I added that the "Command" property must be edited to add or remove skill

You would also have to set the CommandParameter property.

of course! Maybe I should have explained more.

That explanation would make it a better answer.


First, you must define the Skills enum as a flagged enum:
[Flags]
public enum Skills // Don't append 'Enum' to the type name!
{
  None = 0, // An enum that follows the best practice always defines the '0' value
  Strength = 1,
  Intelligence = 2,
  Luck = 4
}


Then use the flagged enum to replace the List<Skills> property. It's also important that Person implements INotifyPropertyChanged as it serves as a binding source, and in addition, has at least one changing property (Skills):
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  // TODO::Must raise the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event!
  public Skills Skills { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }
}


Initialize the Person properly. Don't forget to raise the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event from the CurrentPerson property. Additionally, provide an ICommand implementation to toggle the Skills of the Currentperson. I recommend using a RelayCommand.
The RelayCommand implementation used in this example is taken from Microsoft learn: Relaying Command Logic.
This command will toggle the enum value of the Person.Skills property following the toggle state of the CheckBox that triggers the command via the ChekcBox.Command property.
The CheckBox.CommandParameter value will be the enum value that the CheckBox represents:
public class InitAppViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{    
  // TODO::Must raise the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event!
  public Person CurrentPerson { get; set; }   

  public RelayCommand SetCurrentPersonSkillsCommand 
    => new RelayCommand(
      ExecuteSetCurrentPersonSkillsCommand, 
      CanExecuteSetCurrentPersonSkillsCommand
      commandParameter => this.CurrentPerson is not null)

  public InitAppViewModel()
  {
    this.CurrentPerson = new Person 
    { 
      Name = "Foo", 
      Skills = Skills.Luck | Skills.Intelligence 
    };
  }

  private bool CanExecuteSetCurrentPersonSkillsCommand(object commandParameter)
    => this.CurrentPerson is not null && commandParameter is Skills;

  private bool ExecuteSetCurrentPersonSkillsCommand(object commandParameter)
  {  
    var skills = (Skills)commandParamter;

    // Toggle the enum value to reflect the CheckBox behavior
    this.CurrentPerson.Skills ^= skills;
  }
}


Define a IMultiValueConverter that actually converts the flagged enum to a boolean for each individual CheckBox (where each CheckBox represents an enum flag). The input of the converter is the enum flag that the current CheckBox represents and the currentt Person. the converter simply checks if the Person.Skills contains the current Skills flag:
public class HasFlagConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    Skills predicate = values.OfType<Skills>().First();
    Person currentPerson = values.OfType<Person>().FirstOrDefault();

    // Use bit-masking to check whether a flag is set.
    // Returns TRUE if flag is present otherwise FALSE.
    return currentPerson is not null 
      && (currentPerson.Skills & predicate) != 0;
  }

  // CheckBox.IsChecked binds TwoWay. However, we don't send back any value. Instead, the value is set via the ICommand
  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    => new object[] { Binding.DoNothing, Binding.DoNothing };
}


Finally, use a ContentControl to present the current Person. Define the  ContentControl.ContentTemplate to layout the object. You can use a ObjectDataProvider to actually generate the data source (the collection of enumeration values) for the ItemsControl:
<Window xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <InitAppViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Window.Resources>
    <!-- Basically call Enum.GetValues(typeof(Skills)) -->
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="SkillsEnumDataSource"
                        ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}"
                        MethodName="GetValues">
      <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="local:Skills" />
      </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>

    <!-- The IMultiValueConverter implementation -->
    <local:HasFlagConverter x:Key="HasFlagConverter" />
  </Window.Resources>

  <ContentControl x:Name="PersonPresenter" 
                  Content="{Binding CurrentPerson}">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
          <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SkillsEnumDataSource}}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox"
                          Content="{Binding}"
                          Command="{Binding ElementName=PersonPresenter, Path=DataContext.TestCommand}"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                  <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HasFlagConverter}">
                      <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        <Binding Path="." />
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}"
                                 Path="Content" />
                      </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                    </MultiBinding>
                  </CheckBox.IsChecked>
                </CheckBox>

                <DataTemplate.Triggers>

                  <!-- 
                    We have to hide the Skills.None value 
                    (Skills.None is represented by all CheckBoxes being unchecked) 
                  -->
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}"
                               Value="{x:Static local:Skills.None}">
                    <Setter TargetName="CheckBox"
                            Property="Visibility"
                            Value="Collapsed" />
                  </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
  </ContentControl>
</Window>




The way I solved this issue was to create a new class extendeding the standard WPF CheckBox with two new properties

One which is bound to a common property shared between all extended
checkbox instances (in a group)
One which is set to a specific element from the
flags enum representing the value for this checkbox.

The Checked and Unchecked events are used to perform the bitwise calculation on the shared property value when the checked state changes.
/// <summary>
/// An extended CheckBox control for selecting a specific item from a Flags Enum type
/// </summary>
public class perFlagsCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    public perFlagsCheckBox()
    {
        Checked += (s, e) => IsCheckedChange();
        Unchecked += (s, e) => IsCheckedChange();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The overall selection from multiple perFlagsCheckBox controls
    /// Bind this against a property of the Flags Enum type
    /// </summary>
    public Enum FlagsEnumValue
    {
        get => (Enum) GetValue(FlagsEnumValueProperty);
        set => SetValue(FlagsEnumValueProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FlagsEnumValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FlagsEnumValue", typeof(Enum), typeof(perFlagsCheckBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnFlagsEnumChanged));

    private static void OnFlagsEnumChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (!(obj is perFlagsCheckBox fcb))
        {
            return;
        }

        fcb.IsChecked = fcb.FlagsEnumValue.HasFlag(fcb.CheckedValue);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The value corresponding to this perFlagsCheckBox instance
    /// Bind or set this to a specific element from the Flags Enum
    /// </summary>
    public Enum CheckedValue
    {
        get => (Enum) GetValue(CheckedValueProperty);
        set => SetValue(CheckedValueProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckedValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CheckedValue", typeof(Enum), typeof(perFlagsCheckBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    // update the FlagsEnum value when this perFlagsCheckBox is checked or unchecked
    private void IsCheckedChange()
    {
        if (FlagsEnumValue == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // convert the flags enum value and checked value to the underlying type of the
        // enum (usually Int32), so that we can perform bitwise arithmetic on them.
        var enumType = FlagsEnumValue.GetType();
        var underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(enumType);
        dynamic flagsEnumValueAsUnderlyingType = Convert.ChangeType(FlagsEnumValue, underlyingType);
        dynamic checkedValueAsUnderlyingType = Convert.ChangeType(CheckedValue, underlyingType);

        var newFlagsValueEnumAsUnderlyingType = IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault()
            ? flagsEnumValueAsUnderlyingType | checkedValueAsUnderlyingType
            : flagsEnumValueAsUnderlyingType & ~checkedValueAsUnderlyingType;

        if (newFlagsValueEnumAsUnderlyingType == flagsEnumValueAsUnderlyingType)
        {
            return;
        }

        // convert the new value back to the enum type
        FlagsEnumValue = Enum.ToObject(enumType, newFlagsValueEnumAsUnderlyingType);
    }
}

More details on my blog post.

You need to change some things
    <ItemsControl x:Name="CurrentPerson_Skills" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Skills}}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding}"
Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}, Path=DataContext.Changed}"
CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
            <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SkillConverter}">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}" Path="DataContext.CurrentPerson.Skills"/>
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" Path="Content"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </CheckBox.IsChecked>
        </CheckBox>          
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

Change Person Class and SkillEnum:
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public SkillsEnum Skills { get; set; } // <-- The skills of the user
}

[Flags]
public enum SkillsEnum // <-- All available skills
{
    Strength = 1,
    Intelligence = 2,
    Luck = 4
}

In Converter
public class SkillToBoolConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((SkillsEnum)values[0] & (SkillsEnum)values[1]) == (SkillsEnum)values[1];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

and in InitAppViewModel Class:
    public Person CurrentPerson { get; set; }
    public ICommand Changed { get; set; }
    
    public InitAppViewModel()
    {
        CurrentPerson = new Person() 
        { Name = "Foo",
            Skills = SkillsEnum.Luck| SkillsEnum.Intelligence
        };
        Changed = new RelayCommand(DoChanged);
    }
    
    public void DoChanged(object checkbox)
{
    bool ischecked = ((CheckBox)checkbox).IsChecked.Value;
    SkillsEnum skill = (SkillsEnum)((CheckBox)checkbox).Content;
    if (ischecked)
    {
        CurrentPerson.Skills |= (SkillsEnum)skill;
    }
    else 
    {
        CurrentPerson.Skills &= ~(SkillsEnum)skill;
    }
}


This is overly complicated. You know that CheckBox has a Command property? That you could directly bind an ICommand to a CheckBox? 99.9% you don't need those interaction triggers. They usually only overcomplicate things.

Yes, you were right. I modified the code

You must never reference any controls (or view objects in general) from the view model. That would break the MVVM pattern. Because CheckBox is a toggle control you can toggle the enum flag using XOR to further simplify the implementation. For this, you should pass the current enum flag as command parameter. Please see my answer to understand what I mean.
